# Are (washer) seats in hose bibs, themselves replaceable (i.e., do they screw into the hose bib body) as with some other high-end bathroom faucets?

Tags: washer, outdoorfaucet

My assumption is that such seats cannot be unscrewed/replaced since I see no hex insert by which to unscrew the seat. Attached photo  shows about half the seat's missing...

Not sure how to tell if this hose bib is threaded or soldered. I'm guessing that it IS threaded and can be removed since there looks to be a wrench grip seating (two flat parallel sides for a crescent or pipe wrench) on the wall side of the outer body. Can I assume that a solderable hose bib would NOT have this wrench grip feature?

Thx for your advice. - Roger

Comment: please post a bigger picture

Comment: your two questions make no sense ... neither one asks `how to replace valve seats?`, which seems to be what you actually want to know

Comment: You tagged it as outdoor faucet, so maybe a garden hose?  If garden hose, take an axe, snip off the end and get a repair end to put on the hose.  Easy peasy.

Comment: Hose bibb valves have replaceable seats the same as  most other valves.

Comment: Your picture seems to have gone to the great bit-bucket in the sky. Please [edit] your post to include the picture.